# The remote name could not be resolved "rendering" error in experience editor

Tags: jss, experience-editor, docker, container, nextjs

I am using `Sitecore 10.2` and did the local setup by following the below link--

https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/hd/200/sitecore-headless-development/walkthrough--setting-up-a-development-environment-with-the-sitecore-containers-template-for-next-js.html

The containers are downloaded and the installation is successful but the Experience Editor of the `next js-JSS` homepage is throwing this error.

[image]

When I start the containers using `docker-compose start`, the other containers get started but the "Node Js" container and "Solution" container show failed.

Has anyone encountered this issue? Please let me know if anyone has found a solution for this issue?

Thanks,
Shakti

Answer (score 1):

There could be many different reasons.

Run `docker container ls -a`, and it will list all containers. Find the ID of `rendering` component. Then run `docker container logs [ID for rendering component]`. It will give you the latest logs of `rendering` container: why it doesn't start. And you will be able to figure out what is wrong with the container. If this information will not give you enough details to fix the issue, please update the question with logs.

Comment: yeah, the rendering container logs have this error -- 'npm' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: The webpage is throwing below error--

"404 page not found"